# How to get Dimension Breadcrumb in Excel pulling from Microsoft SSAS

Tags: excel, ssas, data-warehouse, olap-cube, dimensional-modeling

**TL;DR:** How can I enable the option to precede the hierarchy name by the dimension name?

I am trying to implement a change that appears in one of the cubes I am working on based on the same dimension in another cube. When a user creates a pivot table on top of the correct cube in Excel, the dimension list appears as:

[image: Dimension With Breadcrumb on Hierarchy Name]

Where the hierarchy is preceded by the dimension name. When I implement the same dimension on my cube, it appears as:

[image: Dimension Without Breadcrumb on Hierarchy Name]

This is different in that the *example cube has the Dimension name* preceding the Hierarchy *while my working cube does not*.

I looked through the properties of the dimensions and they appear to be the same. Specifically, the *HierarchyUniqueNameStyle* property of the dimension is set to *IncludeDimensionName*. My intuition says that this difference might be on the cube itself, since multiple dimensions of the example cube have the same feature.

Is there is another place where cube display attributes reside? Or, is this something where the developer of the example cube just changed the name?

Comment: What is in the cube property HierarchyUniqueNameStyle of this dimension? ExcludeDimensionName or IncludeDimensionName?

Comment: It is set to IncludeDimensionName. I'm still looking for the answer and will update/answer the question as I find out more.

Comment: It appears that the differentiation only happens in the cube if the dimension is a degenerate dimension. Only then will it apply that, so that the attributes in the dimension can be shown to be a part of which dimension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for the bread crumb to show up, it requires two things. The first thing that is required is that the `IncludeDimensionName` property on the dimension must be set to `true`.

Secondly, the dimension must be a role-playing dimension, or, in other words, used in the cube multiple times.

When both of those conditions are satisfied, the bread crumb as shown in the first picture will appear.

Comment: I thought I understood the meaning of a "degenerate" dimension until I read your comment "in other words, used in the cube multiple times" - I have not seen this extra qualification before. Could you please explain it or point me to a reference that explains it?

Comment: I will look into this some more and see if I can find something. When I originally posted this, I had been out of school for less than 6 months. Since then I've learned a lot and I think I was mistaken in the vocabulary. It appears that what I said was a degenerate dimension is in fact a role-playing dimension. Thank you for bringing this to my attention as I had forgotten about it until now. I'll get my answer updated when I get the chance, or you may update it as well

Comment: And I just updated it. Didn't realize the app could edit until after my earlier comment.

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense - thanks so much for taking the time to clarify for me, and sorry for dragging you back in time so far ;)